# How to use js to query shadow dom element in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer, shadow-dom

I know how to query shadow dom element in `<style>` tag,but i want to use data-bind dynamically change the style,data-bind can not be applied in `<style>` in Polymer,so i should make it happen in js.For example,i use `core-scroll-header-panel`  component, i can query its background style using:

```
<style>
    core-scroll-header-panel::shadow #headerBg {
          background: #5cebca;
        }

</style>
```

but how can implement it in js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way to select your element:

```
var shadow = document.querySelector('core-scroll-header-panel').shadowRoot;
var header = shadow.querySelector('#headerBg');
```

> Note that it will return one single element. If you need to loop over multiple element you may use querySelectorAll as you probably know.

You can then change your background color as normal:

```
header.style.backgroundColor = "#5cebca";
```

However, changing a color in directly in JavaScript is not adviced and you should use *CSS* for that.

```
header.className = "my_css_class";
```

Note that it will return one single element. If you need to loop over multiple element you may use `querySelectorAll` as you probably know.

Comment: yeah,but data-biding can not be applied in <style> tag,i with to change the background according to the content,so i have to do so.but Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you change toggle the class instead to change the color? You could also benefit from transitions and any other style property change at the same time ;) `header.className = 'mystyle'`.

Comment: yeah,right,that's the alternative ,you woke me up,thanks,shame on me~

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it out :

```
document.querySelector('core-scroll-header-panel::shadow #headerBg');
```

and is there any else solutions?